# como validar formulario com retorno do ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

não estou conseguindo fazer a validação do formulário nesse campo que retorna do ajax, função: validarVeiculos(); Como fazer a validação dos checkbox que retornam do ajax?

Tenho uma página principal.php onde declaro a chamada por ajax, nessa página eu include "cadastroAplicacao.php"; que retorna na principal.php => Selecione a montadora...

chamada Ajax: function buscarModelos(){ var montadora = $('#montadora').val(); if(montadora){ // alert('getVeiculos.php?montadora='+montadora); var url = 'getVeiculos.php?montadora='+montadora; $.get(url, function(dataReturn) { $('#checkVeiculos').html(dataReturn); }); }

Código da pagina que retorna ajax:

```
$montadora = ($_GET['montadora'] ? filter_var($_GET['montadora'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : NULL); 
$idVeic = (!empty($_GET['idVeic']) ? filter_var($_GET['idVeic'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : NULL);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM INTEGRAPRODUTOS.fipeVeiculos v WHERE v.IDmontadoraFipe = {$montadora} ORDER BY v.nomeVeiculo ";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $con_local);
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
$html = '';

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){



while ($dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      //echo "<option value='{$dados_Subcategorias['codigo_subcategoria']}'>".utf8_encode($dados_Subcategorias[nome_subcategoria])."</option>";
      if($dados[idVeiculo] == $idVeic){
            ?>
        <div  class='box'; >&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" checked class="<? echo utf8_encode($dados['nomeVeiculo'])?>" id="veiculo" value="<? echo $dados['idVeiculo']?>" name="modelos[]" onClick="document.getElementById('listarFipe').click();" /><? echo utf8_encode($dados['nomeVeiculo'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;"?> </div>
          <?}   
          else {

            ?>
        <div  class='box'; >&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"  class="<? echo utf8_encode($dados['nomeVeiculo'])?>" id="veiculo" value="<? echo $dados['idVeiculo']?>" name="modelos[]" onClick="document.getElementById('listarFipe').click();" /><? echo utf8_encode($dados['nomeVeiculo'])."&nbsp;&nbsp;"?> </div>
          <?}  
     } 

}
```

Validação se selecionou algum checkbox da pagina em ajax (esta na principal.php):

```
<!-- validacao campos -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        //validar veiculos selecionados
        function validarVeiculos(){
        d = document.form;
        var ok = 0;
        var ckbox = d.getElementsByName('modelos[]');
            for (var i=0; i < ckbox.length; i++){
               if(ckbox[i].checked == true){
                ok = 1;
               }
           }

           if(ok == 0){
           alert('Selecione um veículo');
           return false;
           }
        }

function validaForm(){
           d = document.form;

    if (d.codMenil.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Digite um codigo");
        var codMenil = d.getElementByName(codMenil);
        d.codMenil.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (d.Referencia.value.length == 0) {
        //alert("Digite uma Referencia");
        var Referencia = d.getElementByName(Referencia); //Seleciona o campo com a ID "nome"
        d.Referencia.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (d.grupoCategoria.value.length == 0) {
        //alert("Selecione uma Categoria");
        var grupoCategoria = d.getElementByName(grupoCategoria);
        d.grupoCategoria.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (d.Subcategorias.value.length == 0) {
        //alert("Selecione uma Subcategoria");
        var Subcategorias = d.getElementByName(Subcategorias);
        d.Subcategorias.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (d.montadora.value.length == 0) {
        //alert("Selecione uma Montadora");
        var montadora = d.getElementByName(montadora);
        d.montadora.focus();
        return false;
    }

    validarVeiculos();


document.form.submit();
}
```

chamo a funcao que esta dentro

```
<input name="gravar" type="submit" value="Gravar" onclick="return validaForm()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos problemas é que você não esta manipulando o valor retornado por `validarVeiculos()`. Faça o seguinte:

```
if ( !validarVeiculos() ) {
    return false;
}
document.form.submit();
```

Note também que você nunca retorna `true` neste método, e o seletor esta errado: utilize `getElementsByName('modelos')`, sem os `[]`.

Sua função `validarVeiculos()` pode ser otimizada: quando se encontra um modelo `checked`, não é necessário iterar pelos demais modelos. E, se quiser, pode fazer uso do método `Array.some()`:

```
function validarVeiculos() {
    var i, ii, nodes;
    nodes = document.form.getElementsByName('modelos');
    for ( i = 0, ii = nodes.length; i < ii; i++ ) {
        if ( nodes[i].checked ) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    alert("Selecione um veículo!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: alterei minha funcao,mas nao valida: function validaForm(){
           d = document.form;
 
 if (d.codMenil.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Digite um codigo");
  var codMenil = d.getElementByName(codMenil);
        d.codMenil.focus();
        return false;
    }
 
 if (d.Referencia.value.length == 0) {
        //alert("Digite uma Referencia");
  var Referencia = d.getElementByName(Referencia); //Seleciona o campo com a ID "nome"
        d.Referencia.focus();
        return false;
    }

 validarVeiculos();
  
if ( !validarVeiculos() ) {
    return false;
}
document.form.submit(); 
}

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9fsmhLdt/

Comment: estudei melhor a rotina, não vou trabalhar com checkbox, irei utilizar select, nesse caso já implementei a validação em outros selects com retorno de ajax

Comment: @luisricardo não coloque códigos em comentários... edite sua pergunta com o código, sempre identando, pois fica muito mais legível. No meu código tem um erro: `getElementsByName` não retorna um `Array` e sim um `NodeList`, que não possui o método `some`. Vou atualizar minha resposta apenas por referência, já que modificou o algorítmo.